# Seeking Public ArcSDE Server?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am product testing and would like a sample ArcSDE server to connect to for testing.

Does anyone know of ones that are still out there available?

Comment: What is your use case for needing to use ArcSDE? ArcGIS clients have been connecting directly to databases without the need for this middleware for quite a while now. You also have to run a post-install, can only administer though command line - it's not a fun thing to work with.  Is there some kind of legacy system that you need to interface with?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that ArcSDE no longer exists as something to which you can connect (deprecated at 10.2 and removed at 10.3).  The few remaining (and no longer supported) application servers should all be behind firewalls.

You would need to find a site that allows SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2,... connections to strangers. Most DBAs take great care to *avoid* letting random users connect to their database, so I doubt this request will go far.

At a minimum, you're going to need VPN access to a customer database, or, more likely, you'll need to stand up your own RDBMS (or RDS), enable an enterprise database in that (which will require a Server license), and test from there.